# How to define a body-centered ICRF/J2000 frame in SPICE?

Tags: python, frames, spice

I am trying to define a reference frame in SPICE that is

- Centered on a particular body, for example Mars, and
- with axes parallel to J2000/ICRF

After going through the [required reading for reference frames](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/req/frames.html) it's still not clear to me how to proceed. This is what I tried, based on [one of the examples](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/req/frames.html#Gaining%20Flexibility%20via%20TK%20Frames):

```
   \begindata

      FRAME_MARSJ2000          = 4990000
      FRAME_4990000_NAME       = 'MARSJ2000'
      FRAME_4990000_CLASS      = 4
      FRAME_4990000_CLASS_ID   = 4990000
      FRAME_4990000_CENTER     = 499

      TKFRAME_4990000_SPEC     = 'MATRIX'
      TKFRAME_4990000_RELATIVE = 'J2000'
      TKFRAME_4990000_MATRIX   = ( 1,
                                   0,
                                   0,
                                   0,
                                   1,
                                   0,
                                   0,
                                   0,
                                   1 )

   \begintext
```

However, it seems to me that it's only using the rotation information, and not using the `_CENTER` as an offset:

```
In [39]: import spiceypy as spice
    ...: spice.tkvrsn('TOOLKIT')
    ...: spice.furnsh("mars_j2000.tf")
    ...: spice.furnsh("/home/juanlu/Downloads/GMAT/R2018a/data/planetary_ephem/spk/DE421AllPlanets.bsp")
    ...: spice.spkezr("mars", 0.0, "j2000", "none", "ssb")[0][:3]
    ...: 
    ...: 
Out[39]: array([ 2.06980542e+08, -1.86369836e+05, -5.66723310e+06])

In [40]: spice.spkezr("mars", 0.0, "marsj2000", "none", "ssb")[0][:3]
Out[40]: array([ 2.06980542e+08, -1.86369836e+05, -5.66723310e+06])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it even using the rotation information? Unless I'm missing something, you're getting the exact same answer in both cases, there isn't even a correction for rotation. Try "MARSJ2000" in all caps to see if that helps, but regular SPICE complains if you try to use a non-existent frame.

Comment: @barrycarter the matrix is the identity, so the fact that it's not changing due to rotation is at least acceptable. I expected a translation though.

Comment: Try tweaking the matrix to see if it's even reading the file. Or use strace or something. First step debugging: make sure it sees the file.

Comment: I've been suggested on Twitter that this cannot be done: https://twitter.com/DegenerateConic/status/1036380843823038464

Comment: You can always change "ssb" to 499 or "mars" or something in line 40. Although I'm guessing this is just test code, not what you're actually trying to do.